# Why is $\mathbf{d}^{t} H \mathbf{d}$ the second directional derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$, why does $\mathbf{d}^{t} H \mathbf{d}$ give the second derivative to $f$ along the unit vector $\mathbf{d}$? Here $H$ is the Hessian, so that $H_{ij} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$. I suppose I don't have the right definition to work with, so any intuition would be helpful, as well as formal proof. (e.g. why this works in the second order taylor series expansion)

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your definition, you could actually just carry out the matrix multiplication and use some examples like the basis vectors $e_i$.

Comment: @Triatticus could you carry out one such calculation?

Comment: I believe it would be something like $\sum_i \sum_j H_{ij}d_i d_j$. The for example if d is the first unit vector $e_1$ this means $d_i=d_j=1$ for $i=j=1$ and zero otherwise, this yields $H_{11}d_1d_1=H_{11} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1}$

Comment: @Triatticus yes i agree. but why is this the right second derivative?

Comment: why that double sum is the correct object to use I mean

Comment: @AnthonyPeter do you have some *other* definition of the "second derivative of $f$ along a unit vector" that we could start from?

Comment: Oh, that's due to it being $d^T ( H d)$ first you perform the inner matrix product which produces a vector whose components are a summation that you then dot with $d^T$ which produces another summation

Comment: @AnthonyPeter alternatively: can we start from the assumption that this makes sense when $d$ is taken from the standard basis, e.g. $d = (1,0,\dots,0)$?

Comment: This arises naturally when you look at the Taylor series for $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function of one variables given by $g(t)=f(x+td)$. You want to compute $g''(0)$. So you need to use the chain rule. You get $g'(t)=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x+td)d_i$ and 
$g''(t)=\sum_i\sum_j\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x+td)d_i d_j$. So
$g''(0)=\sum_i\sum_j\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)d_i d_j= d^tH(x)d$.